# Build failed with an exception after flutter upgrade

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors, flutter-dependencies

After updating flutter got this error.In pubspec.yaml it is sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0". It was working fine till upgrade.

Error Message

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../Desktop/Development-App/Flutter/fluttersdk/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/flex.dart:926:9: Error: 'Contathrow' isn't a type.
        Contathrow constraintsError;
        ^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/apple/Desktop/Development-App/Flutter/fluttersdk/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1005

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/apple/Desktop/Development-App/Flutter/fluttersdk/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 23s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Solution tried:

1. flutter clear
2. flutter pub get
3. invalidate and restart.
4. flutter upgrade
5. Flutter doctor is upto dated

All my flutter projects have this same issue.

Comment: Could you please clarify, is Contathrow the type defined by you, or is it a part of some library? It isn't seem to be a valid type. Maybe it's a typo?

Comment: It is not a part of any plugin.